# Custom handler in express.js router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working for simple meal info page, and I need to run static and dynamic (json) server in one process, like this:

```
*- root
  +- index.html
  +- res
  | +- main.js
  | +- index.css
  | `- (and more)
  +- meal
  | `- custom handler here (json reqestes)
  `- share
    `- (static files, more)
```

static files will handled with `express.static`, Can I route this with express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all requests without starts with /meal/ should served as static, like /res or (root)/anyfolder/anyfile

`app.use('/share', express.static('share'));` makes the static handler look in `share/`, not the project root. It's unusual to share the whole root because people can read your source code. Do you really need to serve the whole folder? Can you e.g. put `res/` inside `share/`, and then make a symlink pointing `res -> share/res/`, then when a client makes a request `res/main.js` express knows to look in `share/res/main.js`.

Anyway @hexacyanide's code should handle your case, just make sure to order your middleware functions such that Express handles routing functions before static files:

```
app.use(app.router)
app.use('/share', express.static('share'));

app.get('/meal/:param', function(req, res) {
  // use req.params for parameters
  res.json(/* JSON object here */);
});
// if you want to prevent anything else starting with /meal from going to
// static just send a response: 
//app.get('/meal*', function(req, res){res.send(404)} ); 

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

Comment: `Do you really need to serve the whole folder?`
yes i need, this root is not (original) project folder and does not contain whole source code.

Comment: It's up to you how to organize your files, personally I place my server-side javascript code above or adjacent to directories that are served as static. You should be able to replace `app.use('/share', express.static('share'));` with `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` to serve the directory where the process is executed from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with Express. Your setup might look like this:

```
app.use('/share', express.static('share'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
app.get('/meal/:param', function(req, res) {
  // use req.params for parameters
  res.json(/* JSON object here */);
});
```

Where you have a static file server mounted to `/share` and routed to the directory called `/share`, a route at `/` which sends the file called `index.html`, and a route that accepts a parameter, that responds with JSON.

Anything that isn't caught by a route will be attempted to be processed by the static file server. If the file server doesn't find a file, then it will respond with a 404.

Comment: all requests without starts with `/meal/` should served as static, like /res or (root)/anyfolder/anyfile

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? I thought you stated that `meal` requests serve JSON, and you mentioned that elsewhere that the JSON you wanted to server was dynamic.

Comment: if url starts with `/m/`, processed by json handler, or else, static

Comment: My example still applies. Anything that isn't `/` or `/meal/` is served as static files. You just need to change the example to your purposes.